# how to delete a image from iphone application

Tags: iphone

I am working an iphone app where i am giving the option of downloading an image to user's iphone. Following is my code for downloading of image.

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]]];
NSString *pngFilePath = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",docDir] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",couponID]] stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
[data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];
```

My above code works fine but now i want to give option of deleting the image downloaded from above code. Can some one please advice me how can i delete a image file from iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use removeItemAtPath method http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/removeItemAtPath:error:.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:pngFilePath error:NULL];
```

**Return Value**

> YES if the removal operation is
>   successful. If the operation is not
>   successful, but the delegate returns
>   YES from the
>   `fileManager:shouldProceedAfterError:removingItemAtPath:`
>   message, `removeItemAtPath:error:` also
>   returns `YES`. Otherwise this method
>   returns `NO`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:pngFilePath error:NULL];
```